# Synaptic Package Manager Closes Right After it Opens

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Every time I open synaptic, update manager, software center, or ubuntu tweak (basically any package manager).. the app will pop up for a split second then close. I have tried restarting but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out via [this forum post](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/debian-linux-help/80216-apt-get-segmentation-fault.html).

All I had to run was `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin` in the Terminal.

Thanks to Joril for helping me figure out what to look for.

Comment: This works. I have no idea why the other answer has an up vote.

Comment: I upvote'd it because it actually did provide me with enough information to google and figure out the answer. =)

Answer (score 2):

You should try starting the application from the command line and see if there's an error message, e.g.

```
sudo synaptic
```

Comment: This responds with `Segmentation fault`

O_o This is a brand new Wubi installation on a new HDD